# "Floating" view inside scrollable container

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout, scrollview

I was wondering if it is possible to implement such behavior on Android.

[image: Example of behaviour.]

Black square is screen bounds.
Blue square is some parent placed inside big scrollable container (not shown on the picture).
Red square is child view.

I'm interested in very special vertical positioning of the child view during scrolling of the parent.

Child view should be:

- attached to the parent's top if it is scrolled below the top of the screen (pictures 1 and
- attached to the screen's top if parent's top is scrolled above the screen but there is still enought place for child view in visible part of the parent. (picture 3)
- attached to the parent's bottom if parent's top is scrolled above the screen and there is not enought place for child view in visible part of the parent. (picture 4)

Comment: Isn't screen 1 and 4 works differently. I mean you can either try for screen 1 where the view is not at all in picture when the parent is out. Or you can think of trying 4 where the sub view is always visible irrespective parent is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think android has not any straightforward method for doing this, but you can do this with using `RelativeLayout` as parent for floating object, and control its padding by yourself.